# Cassandra timestamp questions

Tags: java, cassandra, timestamp, cqlsh

Multipart question:
1. How do I find/set the default timestamp format?
2. I have a timestamp column that I need to insert into - but I only have time (no date or year) - **how do I do this**? (Does this even make sense)

I ran some basic tests to experiment, couldn't really resolve anything:

```
CREATE TABLE testts (
            ID int PRIMARY KEY,
            mdate timestamp,            
            ttime timestamp);

INSERT INTO testts (ID , mdate, ttime )
VALUES (1, '2015-10-12', '2014-10-12') ;

INSERT INTO testts (ID , mdate, ttime )
VALUES (2, '2015/10/15', '2013/10/12') ;  //This fails

INSERT INTO testts (ID , mdate, ttime )
VALUES (2, '20151015', '20131012') ;  //Did not put any format

INSERT INTO testts (ID , mdate, ttime )
VALUES (3, '2009-08-12', '1020') ; //my actual data is just time

cqlsh:tests> select * from testts;

 id | mdate                    | ttime
----+--------------------------+--------------------------
  1 | 2015-10-12 07:00:00+0000 | 2014-10-12 07:00:00+0000
  2 | 1970-01-01 05:35:51+0000 | 1970-01-01 05:35:31+0000  //1970 ??
  3 | 2009-08-12 07:00:00+0000 | 1970-01-01 00:00:01+0000  //1970 ??

(3 rows)
```

As above somehow this 1970 is showing up?!

Thanks all,

Comment: It's not a timestamp if it doesn't have all the fields. Don't use `timestamp` if that's not what you want to store. Use columns for each of the time fields you have instead.

Comment: > select * from testtime;

 id | mdate                    | ttime
----+--------------------------+--------------------
  1 | 2015-10-12 07:00:00+0000 | 00:00:00.000001020
  2 | 2014-08-15 07:00:00+0000 | 00:00:00.000000930

(2 rows)

Comment: (The above comment got pre-posted)  Yes it does of makes sense not to use timestamp (unless there is way) . So tried  with the time column type and just entered time like 1020, 930 etc, but the select gets **0s** in front - what do they mean- doesn't seem like date/year `> select * from testtime;

 id | mdate                    | ttime
----+--------------------------+--------------------
  1 | 2015-10-12 07:00:00+0000 | 00:00:00.000001020
  2 | 2014-08-15 07:00:00+0000 | 00:00:00.000000930

(2 rows)`

Answer (score 0):

From [the official documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/timestamp_type_r.html) (if this is a visualization problem):

> You can change the format by setting the time_format property in the
>   [ui] section of the cqlshrc file.

In the same link you can find all the information you need to know. Specifically:

> Values for the timestamp type are encoded as 64-bit signed integers
>   representing a number of milliseconds since the standard base time
>   known as the epoch: January 1 1970 at 00:00:00 GMT.

You time-only insert will be then relative to that date, and will show up as is.

Instead of using a `timestamp` column you could use a plain `int` (or `bigint`, depending on your needs) to store the time-only part.